# What are the family of geodesics/curves between point weights/balls on an elastic sheet?

Tags: analytic-geometry, physics, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics, image-processing

**ASSUMPTIONS:**

- no deformation is separate, all deformations touch with at least another points deformation, i.e., no deformation is by itself.
- point force preferred, but small dense balls okay too.
- The point forces are all identical (or balls have the same weight and size.)
- While the deformations touch, no balls touch.
- infinite elastic medium
- isotropic material
- linear elasticity
- homogeneous material
- static loading
- no pre-stress or pre-strain
- flat surface before deformation
- 2D analysis
- neglecting body forces

Below is a picture that represents the phenomenon, except that the ball on the right is by itself, that I got from [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106759/175840) [image: Balls on a Cloth]

And below are the best I could do to demonstrate examples of two curves. Essentially the shape of the threads while ignoring weaving.

Curve 1:
[image: This is the first curve representing connecting two balls.]

Curve 2:
[image: This is the second curve representing a different connection between two balls.]

Comment: You might hint at the start that the balls/weight are stationary, that you do consider a static, not dynamic setup.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I added it in the title. Yes, I meant in the static situation. Thank you.

Comment: While I think this is a nice question, the answer would depend heavily on the physics of the "sheet" (and also the weights of each balls). Could you please provide the assumptions regarding how this sheet behaves?

Comment: @BigbearZzz I updated the list of assumptions. Also, I think this is a special case of the "biharmonic problem".

Comment: I think you might need something along these lines, only in rectangular coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane

Comment: And start with a single ball. A portion of the stretched membrane will deform. It will also experience force from adjacent parts of the membrane, further the  vertical component of net force has to cancel out the weight of the ball.

Comment: You show a three-dimensional picture and ask about a two-dimensional analysis. Maybe a three-dimensional solution to the problem of deformation of a thin elastic material will help you?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Great comment. I was considering 2D analysis in the sense that the parameters are only $\theta$ and $r$ or $x$ and  $y$ depending  on the coordinate system where the depth in the $z$-direction is defined in those two variable. But yes, the surface is of course a 3D surface.